# What inefficiency does sharding & partitioning attempt to address?

Tags: performance, partitioning, sharding

I have never implemented sharding or partitioning, but from what I understand, multiple servers are used to distribute large amounts of data.

Is this because of a limited hardware budget or to address end-user latency?

What I mean is that provided an unlimited budget providing for ideal processing, storage, memory, network, etc, would sharding or partitioning be able to still increase performance?

Comment: Sharding and partitioning are different things. Also, your answers may vary depending on which RDBMS perspective the answerer uses.

Comment: It's similar to having multiple partitions on your HDD & Folders on file system.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should get you started to wonder more:

1. [The Basics of Database Sharding](http://www.brentozar.com/archive/2013/05/the-basics-of-database-sharding/)
2. [Shard (database architecture)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29)
3. [Partition (database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_%28database%29)
4. [SQL Server Table Partitioning: Resources](http://www.brentozar.com/sql/table-partitioning-resources/)
5. [SQL Server 2005 Partitioned Tables and Indexes](http://www.sqlskills.com/resources/whitepapers/partitioning%20in%20sql%20server%202005%20beta%20ii.htm)

A lot to read but will give you all the answers that you're looking for!

Comment: @Gracchus, in case of the ideal hardware, it mostly will help with maintenance tasks -- index maintenance, for instance. Interesting question! Hard to tell without testing and looking at the numbers.